# AWS SDK Ruby DynamoDB session_token invalid

Tags: ruby, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I get: The security token included in the request is invalid

Where do I get a session token? The current documentation is confusing. On the one hand it says:

*If you make a request using AWS::DynamoDB with long-term credentials a request is made to Amazon STS for temporary session credentials. These will be cached in the process and re-used.*

and next it says:

*Amazon DynamoDB requires that all requests are made with short-term credentials (e.g. requires a session token).*

so exactly where does the session_token come from if I don't provide it? And if the call provides it, why would it be invalid?

```
requires 'aws-sdk'

cred = {:access_key_id => 'xxxx', 
:secret_access_key => 'yyyy'}

#:session_token => ''}

ddb = AWS::DynamoDB.new(cred)
items = {...}
ddb.batch_write do |batch|
  batch.put('my_mappings', items)
end
```

Comment: Note that in irb, the initiation of a DynamoDB.new works fine with only the :access_key_id and the :secret_access_key. No session_key is necessary. As well, in code, I can work with the 'ddb' handle.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is incorrect/old (its been changed on the master branch in GitHub).  You no longer require session credentials to use DynamoDB.  You should be able to configure just your `:access_key_id` and `:secret_access_key`.

If you do want session credentials, you can get them from `AWS::STS`.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found that the following works.

```
cred = {:access_key_id => 'xxxx', 
:secret_access_key => 'yyyy', :session_token => nil}

ddb = AWS::DynamoDB.new(cred)
```

In my original example, the ddb handle would work for certain operations but not for batch_write. Passing the 'nil' works. The documentation is unclear and the API is inconsistent  in the current version.